# File Upload in IFrame asp .net

Tags: asp.net, iframe, file-upload

I am using Asp .net 3.5 Web Form. VS 10.

I want to do a file upload in a form. But, I don't want to have a post back. I am trying to do it in an iframe. When the FileUpload control change event fired, the `ifrmFileUpload` src will called. where the File Upload will occur and the `lblFile` will show the FileName.

```
<iframe id="ifrmFileUpload" src="">
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" id="btnFileUpload" />
    <asp:label id="lblFile"/>
</iframe>
```

But I want to postback for only the Iframe. And If possible, a HttpHandler file. like UploadHandler.ashx

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    ........ // code here to upload from file
}
```

Comment: You were going in the correct direction. So what have you tried so far? Don't tell me you've put the file upload server control in the iframe like that...! :)

Comment: i have almost done it. please wait :) after finishing, I will share :)
Your comment really make me feel, someone is with me ;)

Comment: So... you accomplish this task?

Comment: Yes, I finished that! but anyway could not upload. And at this moment I dont know where the solution is. from this comment, I feel, I have to search this and will publish here.